# A question of spin in Electron Positron Anahilation

Tags: positronium

I have read the other questions dealing with the spin of the electron and positron, but have a slightly different question.

Does the amount of energy produced in a E-/E+ collision depend on the spin of the 2 particles?  Other words, if I collide a Left handed electron and an left handed positron, would the energy produced be any different, if one was left handed and the other right handed? - I understand the number of photons being produced changes, but would the energy output be different?

Answer (score 1):

The handyness doesnt contribute anything to momentum so the energy output will be the same.